# How to install an older version of vite

Tags: vue.js, vite, quasar-framework

I am trying to use Quasar Framework which doesn't support Vite 4.1 yet. So I need to install some version of Vite in the `3.` range. But how do I do this? The install process I would like to use is:

Like

`npm create vite@latest`

So far I have tied `npm create vite@3` and it doesn't seem to work. It still comes down with the latest packages and Quasar is still complaining.

I am trying to take advantage of the CLI walkthrough that vite offers where it can scaffold Vue, TS, and Pinia automatically, but use an older version of Vite.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason `npm create vite@3` isn't make a vite v3 project (it should), you can always edit the package.json and manually change the vite version and reinstall your packages (delete node_modules, delete package-lock.json, run `npm install`).  Before you do those steps change your list of dependencies and devDependencies to the following:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.15.8",
    "quasar": "^2.10.2",
    "vue": "^3.2.41"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/vite-plugin": "^1.2.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
    "sass": "1.32.12",
    "vite": "^3.2.3"
  }
```

Then just follow the [documentation](https://quasar.dev/start/vite-plugin#using-quasar) for updating `main.js`, `vite.config.js`, and creating the `src/quasar-variables.sass` file.